# SQL query with multiple joins impacting performance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, join

I have a relational MySQL database with almost 4000 records. The contacts table is related to both the keywords and notes tables with manny-to-many relationships. I wrote a query (with PHP) that would retrieve each contact record and, for each contact, all related notes and keywords in a group concat function. If I only grab the contacts, the query performs relatively quickly but with the two left joins and group concat, it takes almost 30 seconds. Is there a way to speed this up?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT n.id, '[-]', n.value, '' SEPARATOR '---') as notes,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT kk.id, '[-]', kk.value) as keywords
    FROM  contacts c
    LEFT JOIN  notes n  ON c.id LIKE n._contactID
    LEFT JOIN  
        ( SELECT  k.*, kc._contactID as contactID
            FROM  keywords k
            INNER JOIN  keywords_contacts kc  ON k.id LIKE kc._keywordID
        ) kk  ON kk.contactID LIKE c.id
    GROUP BY  c.id
    ORDER BY  c.`Last Name`, c.`First Name`
```

Comment: Did you set indexes in your database? Indexes may speed up queries.

Comment: To my way of thinking, there is no problem in SQL for which GROUP_CONCAT need form any part of the answer - especially so when working with application level code. The key to speed will reside with indexes, but before we get to that, consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements together with a desired result

Comment: @Strawberry while I fixed the issue by using Haresh's solution, I am a bit of a noob with SQL and I want to understand your comment. Do you think you could provide a code sample, something I could analyze and play with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I your query I can see `c.id LIKE n._contactID`, here LIKE is making performace low so use = operator and give index to foreign key field `_contactID`.

Same as for `k.id LIKE kc._keywordID` use = operator instead of LIKE and apply index on  field `_keywordID`.

Comment: Ahh thank you, this did the trick! I changed from '=' to 'Like' when I was debugging last week and forgot.

Comment: Thanks to hear from you about my tricks and don't forget to give up vote also.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `=` instead of `LIKE`; keep `LIKE` for when you need wild cards, such as `first_name LIKE 'H%'`.

After changing to `=`, you may still find the query slow.  Consider these:

If you don't need `LEFT`, don't use it.  Normally it is faster to start with the 'table' that is a subquery (see `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ...)`), but the use of `LEFT` tends to inhibit such.

If the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are the same, you can avoid a temp table and sort:

```
GROUP BY c.`Last Name`, c.`First Name`, c.id
ORDER BY c.`Last Name`, c.`First Name`, c.id
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, so we can critique the indexes.